After instance refresh digital experience not working
Our instance got a refresh last night, and now our Experience users cannot login.
We have what appears to be a properly configured SAML configuration.
The authentication provider correctly authenticates the user and links back to our experience.
However, we are getting the boilerplate "Service Not Available" page (as configured in the Workspace) when attempting to log in.
The URL appears to be correct, https://www.[domain.tld]/login?so=00DXXXXXXXXXXXX&sc=0LEXXXXXXXXXXXX.
A different Experience that uses username+password to login is still working fine.
So clearly something changed with regard to SSO, but I don't know what.
The weird thing is, we are not getting an SSO error screen.

I might be talking nonsense but have you tried clearing any existing access tokens that have been provided based on SSO?

Turns out that I was misinformed.
While we first encountered this problem right after the instance refresh - that is not the cause of the problem.
This problem is due to a buggy deploy of a new method to call out to the authentication provider, that coincidentally happened on the same day of the instance refresh.
We addressed that issue - and the more important issue of clear lines of communication within the team.
